# how to detect editing of text in a cell in a tablewidget in pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a tablewidget where the rows are added dynamically, I have to enter a name in the first column which is to be specific so I have a listwidget beside tablewidget where names are displayed from a database, so now how to detect the change in the cell so that I can filter out names in listwidget.

I have tried all the signals which are emitted by tablewidget but no luck, all the signals are emitted after a mouse click or keyboard button, I want to detect a change in a single cell for each letter entered or deleted.

I have tried ItemDelegate too, but it detects only the start of editing, here is my code

```
class ItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    cellEditingStarted = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        result = super(ItemDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if result:
            self.cellEditingStarted.emit(index.row(), index.column())
        return result
 .
 .
 .

self.delegate = ItemDelegate()
self.delegate.cellEditingStarted.connect(self.showlistwidget)
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of detecting when the editor is displayed, you should use the editor's textChanged signal (QLineEdit):

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class StyledItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    editingFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super(StyledItemDelegate, self).createEditor(
            parent, option, index
        )
        if isinstance(editor, QtGui.QLineEdit):
            editor.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
            editor.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinished)
        return editor


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table_widget = QtGui.QTableWidget(4, 4)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Name", "1", "2", "3"))
        delegate = StyledItemDelegate(self.table_widget)
        delegate.textChanged.connect(self.filter)
        delegate.editingFinished.connect(self.clear_filter)
        self.table_widget.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)

        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget()

        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        hlay.addWidget(self.list_widget)

        for letter1 in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            for letter2 in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
                text = letter1 + letter2
                it = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(text)
                self.list_widget.addItem(it)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def filter(self, text):
        self.clear_filter()
        for r in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            it = self.list_widget.item(r)
            # filter algorithm
            is_showing = text in it.text()
            # Hide the row if necessary
            it.setHidden(not is_showing)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def clear_filter(self):
        for r in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            it = self.list_widget.item(r)
            it.setHidden(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```
from functools import partial
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class StyledItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, str)
    editingFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super(StyledItemDelegate, self).createEditor(
            parent, option, index
        )
        if isinstance(editor, QtGui.QLineEdit):
            editor.textChanged.connect(
                partial(self.textChanged.emit, index.row(), index.column())
            )
            editor.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinished)
        return editor


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table_widget = QtGui.QTableWidget(4, 4)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Name", "1", "2", "3"))
        delegate = StyledItemDelegate(self.table_widget)
        delegate.textChanged.connect(self.filter)
        delegate.editingFinished.connect(self.clear_filter)
        self.table_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget()

        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        hlay.addWidget(self.list_widget)

        for letter1 in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            for letter2 in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
                text = letter1 + letter2
                it = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(text)
                self.list_widget.addItem(it)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int, str)
    def filter(self, row, column, text):
        print(row, column)
        self.clear_filter()
        for r in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            it = self.list_widget.item(r)
            # filter algorithm
            is_showing = text in it.text()
            # Hide the row if necessary
            it.setHidden(not is_showing)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def clear_filter(self):
        for r in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            it = self.list_widget.item(r)
            it.setHidden(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  it works perfectly, from where can I learn more on this topic?

Comment: How to replace the editing cell by the item in list when doubleclicked on the item,i have tried using itemdoubleclicked signal emitted by listwidget but no luck,the script starts to loop how to do this task?